# Tkinter: Refresh a window (class-based) while closing another

Tags: python, class, tkinter, window, refresh

I have a program that reads and writes info from a CSV file and displays it in the main window. I can open a separate window to enter data, which closes when some is entered correctly. Here's a simple version:

```
import tkinter as tk
import csv, os

class main(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        with open('filename.csv', 'r') as f:
            #read data and display in main window
    def newwindow(self):
        #new window

class second_window(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        #window stuff
    def data_writer(self):
        with open('filename.csv', 'r+') as f:
            #do stuff
            self.master.destroy()
root = tk.Tk()
app = main(root)
root.mainloop()
```

When the data is entered, it updates the csv file and closes the second window, but the main window obviously doesn't refresh. I've come across some other threads that give some pointers, but none work for my case especially since the two windows are different classes. How can I refresh the main window with the updated data? Could I call `self.master.destroy` on the main window and re-open it, and how would I do that? Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Your with open statement can only happen once during the class installation. Maybe move the with open statement to a separate method and then call that method from the 2nd class to update the main class.

Answer (score 0):

You can still access the 2nd class, including instance objects, even though the window is closed.  Continuing on with the pseudo-code provided:

```
class main(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master=master
        with open('filename.csv', 'r') as f:
            #read data and display in main window
        self.new_window()
        self.print_from_other_class()

    def new_window(self):
        #new window
        self.SW=second_window(self.master)

    def print_from_other_class(self):
        print self.SW.test_of_csv_field  ## or update Text, Label, etc.

class second_window(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        #window stuff
    def data_writer(self):
        with open('filename.csv', 'r+') as f:
            #do stuff
            self.test_of_csv_field="yep, I'm, here"
            self.master.destroy()
```